# Как присвоить переменной значение, равное 1 секунде?

Tags: c#

Как присвоить переменной значение, равное 1 секунде?

Comment: Плохой вопрос. Ничего не понятно.

Comment: Для какой цели это нужно? Опишите проблему.

Comment: int time = 1;  // ;)

Comment: @cy6erGn0m  ))) я тоже так хотел написать, но воздержался ))

Answer (score 8):

```
TimeSpan sec = new TimeSpan(1000);
```